# How do I achieve the 'Bullseye' achievement in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: achievements, jetpack-joyride

I cannot seem to get the Bullseye achievement in Jetpack Joyride

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Jetpack Joyride wikia](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/Bullseye):

> Get a score of exactly 200m.

This requires a good amount of luck.
First of all, don't equip anything that makes you move after you're dead. You need many attempts to understand how space you take to completely stop after a collision. Try and retry several times, it's just a matter of luck, you eventually get the achievement.

Comment: @Allie You're welcome! Please accept one of the answers if they solved your problem :)

Comment: I keep getting up to 199 or 198 :(

Comment: @Allie I know, it's a bit frustrating <.< but keep trying!

Comment: I will ^^. It's gonna take a while though ;-;

Answer (score 4):

To unlock the *Bullseye* achievement in Jetpack Joyride you need to get a score of exactly 200m.

To get this you need to hit a zapper at about 134 meters, depending on how high up it is, this will slide you to 200 meters. The 3rd zapper is generally the one you would want to hit.

It may not be possible to achieve this on some runs and you may have to try many times until you get lucky.

Comment: @Allie no worries, good luck! don't get too frustrated it may take some time